# How should data be formatted between embedded device and app/cloud?

Tags: data, embedded-systems

We have an embedded device collecting data from various sensors attached to it. The data is then passed to the application. What is the best way to design the data packets? The data needs to be hardware agnostic. There's only one hardware device and one main sensor on that device that is collecting the data of interest. However it's possible that in the future more devices and different sensors will be used. New data packets will have to be made. What design would be best for reducing the amount of rework needed to be done?

Our current embedded firmware takes the raw data from the sensor, then parses into a specific sensor data type packet, then sends it to the application. The application then receives the packet, parses it, and then does what it wants with it. This seems good because this is hardware agnostic. If we want to add a new device it just has to implement this limited data packet api. However it seems as though we're doing work in two places (on the embedded and the app) when we could just do it in the app where computing resources are less constrained.

The other implementation that I'm thinking of, is doing no parsing on the embedded. The raw data received from the sensor could be put into a JSON packet as is as "data". The JSON packet could be really simple, it could have a data type field then a blob field. The app would get a data packet (it wouldn't have to care yet what kind of sensor/data it is, it's just data). Then the application would look at the type and see if it has a parsing function available for that type. The only issue with this approach is that now the application has to know about the specific sensor. It wouldn't be that hard or time consuming to look at the datasheet to figure out how to parse the data on the app side, realistically it would just be copying code from the embedded to the app. Is that a good separation of concerns however?

Is it better to implement the packet api on a sensor type basis. For every new sensor that gets added, implement parsing on the embedded and application side ( the parsing on the app would be simpler and wouldn't have to know about the hardware sensor). Or would it be better to pass around data as blobs (processing on the embedded would be simple and the data packet would still be HW agnostic, however there would be additional parsing on the application required)? Or is there another better option?

Comment: You've made a reasonable analysis of the pros and cons of either approach, but we can't make the choice of approach for you. We can't know whether you'd rather speed up development time on the application vs suffer performance penalties by doing embedded calculations. Or whether you would rather keep down the redeployment budget on the embedded devices by pushing as much onto the application as you can. That's a business decision, not a technical one. And it heavily skews which approach you could favor.

Comment: For a lot of systems this already a solved problem by use of [MQTT](https://mqtt.org).  Do you have reasons to re-invent the wheel? (and yes I know there can be valid reasons)